# Best practices for inter thread communication of large objects

Tags: c++, multithreading, caching, boost, lock-free

I need to be extremely concerned with speed/latency in my current multi-threaded project.

Consider the following inter-thread communication:

- Thread #1: Processes a large object, call it `A`, that it receives from network events. This data significantly alters its internal state.
- Thread #2: Needs to know about the current, altered internal state of object `A` to make some set of decisions.

I can think of essentially two methods to proceed:

1. Thread #2 has a pointer to object `A`, and when signaled (say, through constantly checking a small object sent via a lockfree queue or by checking a shared atomic bool), Thread #2 locks object `A` and reads it.
2. Thread #1 pushes some version of a copy of the object onto the lockfree queue so that thread #2 can simply receive it directly, use it, and dispose of the copy when it is finished.

Method #1 avoids the costly copy of a large object needed for Method #2, but it always requires a lock/unlock and, if I understand things correctly, additional L3 cache hits.

I understand there may not be any simple performance answers...that I may simply need to benchmark. I am mostly interested in best practices advice. Specifically, I'd like to know to think about the problem a cache memory level to know how information is being passed and copied internally.

Comment: Is thread #2 allowed to miss some of the changes in your large object A, or does it have to respond to any changes ? In the latter case imho there's almost no way around a queue.

Comment: A lock is going to cost you something less than 50 nanoseconds if it's not contended. Seems like that's a lot less expensive than cloning a very large object and then disposing of the clone when you're done with it. But you also have to consider the frequency of updates. How likely is Thread #1 to have object "A" locked when Thread #2 tries to access it? (Or how often is Thread #1 likely to find that Thread #2 has a lock on the object that Thread #1 wants to update?)

Comment: What I can recommend, is to have shared, access protected object instances when communicating asynchronously with your threads. Check out [Thread support library, Mutual exclusion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread), to solve race conditions.

Comment: @Oncaphillis - correct...it has to respond to every change.

Comment: @PaulD in that case a simple bool flag will not do. Either you establish a kind of queue or fully synchronize read/write cycles. In the latter case the performance/latency heavily (only ?) depends on the speed of the network data coming in.

Comment: @JimMischel - it depends on who has more "free time", I think. There are some needs that I omitted in an attempt to simplify the question. But, in general, thread #2 has "more free time" and thread #1 needs to NOT miss a network event that, as of now, is not being buffered.

Comment: This sounds like you've painted yourself into a painful corner. If there's some work that needs to be done on or with object "A", why does it need to be thread 2 that does it? Why not just have thread 1 do it, while the data is hot in its CPU's cache? If you care about speed/latency in a multi-threaded project, you should not be trying to micromanage which thread does what work. That hurts performance.

Comment: ^ Let me stress my agreement with @DavidSchwartz's comment

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Yes. I knew the corner I painted myself into. :) There are reasons for the separation of threads as they are, though maybe those reasons will be mitigated in future versions of my project. My reason for asking the question was motivated by this exact corner I find myself in and, as of yet, am unable to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on how much information thread 2 is trying to access from thread 1. If it needs complete access of all of thread 1's objects/memory then yeah, copying all that is costly and I'd do a lock. But it also depends on the time. If all thread 2 needs is to check a state like one variable I would have thread 1 update a smaller object outside of itself that can be shared without locks since thread 2 only reads while thread 1 only writes.

Also you might not even need locking if thread 2 only reads and is ok with making a decision on a data state as it updates.

Comment: In most non-trivial cases you'll at least need a write exclusive lock since very often data needs to have internal consistency e.g. if you like to report file info of a remote file this way you'd like to guarantee that filename and filesize are always consistent for the reading thread. (stupid example though)

Comment: I think you are right. Given the discussion, I assume it is not an easy one-size-fits-all situation. It depends on the size of the data, the needs of the consumer, and the relative work load of the different threads. Didn't think my question deserved to get down voted though! :)

Comment: It just depends, a lot of my multi threaded applications are a background thread doing some file processing while a main GUI thread is informing the user of what's going on. In those cases I don't really even need a lock. The GUI thread just checks a status flag that has different states like 1 = files downloading, 2 = files be processed, 3 = idle etc. In those cases I don't really care if the GUI thread reads that state while it's changing values because it doesn't have the be that accurate. The next time it reads it will be up to date. It depends on how sensitive your program is.